# Discord.js blacklist code doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm making this code for blacklisted words and it doesn't work. It doesn't give any errors but doesn't work. How to fix?

```
let blacklisted = ['blacklisted', 'right'];
    let foundInText = false;//
    for(const i in blacklisted) {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted[i])) foundInText = true;
    }
    if (foundInText === true) {
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send('no just no');
    }
```

That is the code so as I have said it doesn't give any errors but just doesn't do anything if I send a blacklisted word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for ... in` logic returns the actual value of the current `blacklisted` object it's iterating over, not the array index of the current value. Because of this, your code is trying to find the value of `blacklisted["blacklisted"]` or `blacklisted["right"]`, which will be undefined and always return false.

To make this work with your current code, you can instead just check whether the message content contains the value of `i`.

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(i)) foundInText = true;
```

However, even if it does find a blacklisted word somewhere towards the start of the list, your code will still iterate over the entire list, due to lacking a `break` keyword when the text is found (you don't need to iterate the list any further if you've already found a match). You can massively simplify your code by using the [`some` array function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which checks if any of the elements of an array satisfies a given condition, immediately returns `true` once it finds any element that satisfies the condition, or `false` if it doesn't find anything.

```
let blacklisted = ["blacklisted", "right"]

let foundInText = blacklisted.some(blacklistWord => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklistWord))

if (foundInText) { // No need for === true on boolean variables
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send('no just no');
}
```